# lighter mesh grid line (faceted) color

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

For certain colormaps, the mesh grid line color is too dark. I would like to make it less dark. However not a fixed color as set with `faceted color=blue,`.

My approach was to adjust the opacity as in this MWE

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[view={0}{90}]
    \addplot3[surf, domain=-2:2, samples=30,colormap/cool] {exp(-x^2-y^2)};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}   

    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[view={0}{90}]
    \addplot3[surf, domain=-2:2, samples=30,colormap/cool,
        opacity=0.2,
        fill opacity=1,
    ] {exp(-x^2-y^2)};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

It looks OK in TexStudio, but not if I open the pdf in chrome where the lines are now whiteisch:

[image]

Anyway I think opacity is the wrong approach. I suppose it is necessary to adjust `shader=flat,draw=\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/faceted color}` (page 139 in the manual) but I don't know how.

Comment: Looks like a viewer issue. Have you tried other PDF viewers?

Comment: Yes, but as I said I think opacity is the wrong way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I found the solution in `pgfplots.code.tex`

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[view={0}{90}]
    \addplot3[surf, domain=-2:2, samples=30,colormap/cool,
        shader=flat,
        draw=mapped color!90!black, % original: mapped color!80!black
    ] {exp(-x^2-y^2)};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```